# Custom Annotation with dynamic argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

Here is my problem :

I have an annotation :

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DummyAnnotation {
String dummyParam1();
String dummyParam2();
}
```

My service is :

```
@Component
public class DummyService {

@DummyAnnotation(dummyParam1="#otp",dummyParam2="#transactionId")
public void dummy(String otp, String transactionId){

}
}
```

My aspect is trying to validate the two arguments and throw exception if the validation don't successed :

```
 @Around(value = "@annotation(annotation)")
public Object verifyOtp(final ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint, final DummyAnnotation  annotation) throws Throwable {
            String transactionId = annotation.dummyParam1();
            String otp = annotation.dummyParam2();
            Boolean otpValid = otpService.verify(transactionId, otp);
            if (otpValid) {
                return jointPoint.proceed();
            }
            else {
                throw new AuthentificationForteException();
            }

}
```

How can i get this working because Spring EL is not working and in my Aspect i have 
dummyAnnotation.dummyParam1() Equal to "#otp" and not to the value of my argument String otp .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I don't really see what are you trying to achieve with this custom annotation, it does not have any validators. What is the aspect you mentioned. Please provide more details.

Comment: I edit my post with the code of the aspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finnaly i find a solution :

The solution is to implement a specific Spring Expression Parser.
I added these declaration to my aspect :

```
private ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
private ParserContext parserContext = new TemplateParserContext();
```

and I changed how I retrieved my dummyValue :

```
@Around(value = "@annotation(annotation)")
public Object verifyOtp(final ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint, final DummyAnnotation  annotation) throws Throwable {

String transactionId = getDummyValue(annotation.dummyParam1(),jointPoint.getArgs());
String otp = getDummyValue(annotation.dummyParam2(),jointPoint.getArgs());

        Boolean otpValid = otpService.verify(transactionId, otp);
        if (otpValid) {
            return jointPoint.proceed();
        }
        else {
            throw new AuthentificationForteException();
        }
```

}

getDummyValue is a method that parse the expression :

```
private String getDummyValue(String authExpression,  Object[] args){
    Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression(authExpression, parserContext);
    String value = expression.getValue(new RootObject(args),String.class);
    return value;
}


private static class TemplateparserContext implements ParserContext{

    @Override
    public boolean isTemplate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getExpressionPrefix() {
        return "#{";
    }

    @Override
    public String getExpressionSuffix() {
        return "}";
    }

}

 protected static class RootObject {

        private final Object[] args;

        private RootObject(Object[] args) {
            super();
            this.args = args;
        }

        public Object[] getArgs() {
            return args;
        }
    }
```

and finally I changde my service and the use of the DummyAnnotation to :

```
 @Component
 public class DummyService {

 @DummyAnnotation(dummyParam1="#{args[0]}",dummyParam2="#{args[1]}")
 public void dummy(String otp, String transactionId){

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't writing an aspect that works against this be simpler?

```
@DummyAnnotation
public void dummy(@Otp String otp, @TransactionId String transactionId){
  ...
}
```

It would also not be Spring-specific, making it easier to test.

(If you intend to traverse into the arguments to extract the OTP or TX ID, e.g. #foo.txId, then this won't work of course, but I think it's simpler otherwise.)

Comment: I am agree but i need to traverse Object , so i don't see how i can do it with "@Otp" and "@Transactionid" annotation